# Jquery Calculation, Remove NaN when input contents are removed

Tags: jquery, html

I'm building a simple calculator where a customer can add credit onto their account, everything is working apart from the below error.

The error:
When you enter a value everything is fine, if you click away and then click back in to edit and delete the value you get a NaN, i want this to default to 0.00 instead of display NaN

Fell free to look at the JS and optimize where you can as I've only butchered this together.

HTML:

```
Credit:
<span id="price01" class="price">&pound;1000.00</span><br/>

Add: <input type="text" id="pricetoadd" placeholder="0.00" name="price02" class="price">

Total: <span class="total"></span>
```

JS:

```
$.fn.sumValues = function() {
        var sum = 0;
        this.each(function() {
            if ( $(this).is(':input') ) {
                var val = $(this).val();
            } else {
                var val = $(this).text();
            }
            sum += parseFloat( ('0' + val).replace(/[^0-9-\.]/g, ''), 10 );
        });
        return sum;
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#pricetoadd').blur(function(){
            var num = parseFloat($(this).val());
            var cleanNum = num.toFixed(2);
            $(this).val(cleanNum);
        if(num < 1){
            $('#error').text('Please enter only 2 decimal places, we have truncated extra points');
            }
        });

        $('input.price').bind('keyup', function() {
            $('span.total').html( $('.price').sumValues().toFixed(2) );
        });
    });
```

Working Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/gRjz7/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a little sanity checker :

```
$('#pricetoadd').blur(function(){
    var num = parseFloat($(this).val());
    var cleanNum = num.toFixed(2);

   cleanNum = isNaN(cleanNum) ? '0.00' : cleanNum;

    $(this).val(cleanNum);

    if(num < 1){
        $('#error').text('Please enter only 2 decimal places, we have truncated extra points');
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/gRjz7/1/)

Comment: +1. Since `NaN` is falsy, you might even write that as `var cleanNum = (num || 0).toFixed(2);`.

Comment: @DavidHedlund - did'nt think about that, but you're right, OR would work as well. I always tend to use ternary's to do simple value checks like that.

Comment: @adeneo if i upgrade to jquery 1.9 it breaks, can you advise?

Comment: @RoyBarber - breaks how exactly ?